# I can't use touchesBegan/Moved/Ended and a UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

Is it not possible to use both of these at the same time. Originally, I have overriden (Swift) touchesBegan/Moved/Ended in my ViewController.

Now, I'm wanting to add a TapGestureRecognizer to certain views under a certain situation, but the selector/action never gets fired.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
...
func addTapGesturesOnNumberPadDisplay() {
    if tapGestureRecognizerNumberPadView == nil {
        tapGestureRecognizerNumberPadView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
        tapGestureRecognizerNumberPadView!.delegate = self
        self.numberViewDone?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizerNumberPadView!)
    }
}
...
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //never hit
```

Is this not possible? Should I just implement my own tapping ability in touchesBegan since I'm overriding it anyway, or is there a way to also use a tapGestureRecognizer here?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have overriden touchesBegan/Moved/Ended  in viewcontroller it should not have any impact on tap gestures in other subviews. Ideally it should work. Please check code below, works as expected.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var categoryScrollView: UIScrollView!
var customView: UIView!
var tapGestureRecognizerNumberPadView : UITapGestureRecognizer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    customView = UIView()
    customView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(50,50)
    customView.frame.size = CGSizeMake(100, 100)
    customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.view.addSubview(customView)
    addTapGesturesOnNumberPadDisplay()
}

func addTapGesturesOnNumberPadDisplay() {
    if tapGestureRecognizerNumberPadView == nil {
        tapGestureRecognizerNumberPadView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
        tapGestureRecognizerNumberPadView!.delegate = self
        self.customView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizerNumberPadView!)
    }
}

func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("handleTap")
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

}
```

}

Please check is there any other gestures to 'numberViewDone' view.

Comment: > it should have have any impact on tap gestures